# get Path of Subsystem

Tags: simulink

For documentation I need ca. 100 times a day the path of the selected/current subsystem.

That means I need some field where I can copy and past the path to use it in a document.

I just know and find the way with the Model Browser. But I have to typ the whole path.

Comment: Have you tried gcs or gcb?

Comment: @Navan What do you mean with gcs or gcb?

Comment: gcs returns currently selected system and gcb returns currently selected block

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, the currently selected block or subsystem can be retrieved by using `gcb`. But it is also possible to copy this directly into the clipboard. Therefore select the to be copied block and use the `clipboard` command:

```
clipboard('copy', gcb);
```

You can also create a Matlab shortcut (right click on the "Shortcut" toolbar and select "New Shortcut") or even a Simulink menu entry with according keyboard shortcut (search Simulink documentation for "sl_customization") for this command, if you use it that frequently.